# Generating Octomap [Solved]

Tags: slam, navigation, rviz, octomap, rgbd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys!

I'm facing some problems trying to generate an Octomap. First of all, I downloaded RGBDSLAM (http://felixendres.github.io/rgbdslam_v2/) and installed as recommended. I'm able to run `roslaunch rgbdslam rgbdslam.launch` and see the map as i capture the frames. My problem is when i try to save this map as an octomap or pointcloud map. None of them are working.

-- As Felix said, the only think you must do to save the octomap is, from the GUI, click on 'Octomap'->'Save Octomap'. **First problem:** When i click on save octomap, i generate a .pcd file, not a .bt. **Second problem:** When i try to open this .pcd file from `rosrun pcl_viewer file.pcd` I got this error: No points to read. **How can i properly save an Octomap after finish my rgbdslam ?**

-- My second attempt was try to use these packages: http://octomap.github.io/ but i don't know and didn't find out how to run this package. In other words, i want to use this to generate my own octomap and, if it's possible, visualize it in RVIZ. I downloaded the latest version (1.6.8) and extract all the folder to my home folder. Then i run the commands to compile and (i think) everythink is ok with that. **So, how can i use this package to create my own map using ROS ?** Also, i tried to follow these instructions (http://wiki.ros.org/octomap) but nothing changed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199244/generating-octomap-%5Bsolved%5D/) by [Thiagopj](https://answers.ros.org/users/19552/thiagopj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-12-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To build an octomap, you might wanna use [`octomap_server`](http://wiki.ros.org/octomap_server). You can change the subcribed topics using remap and them build your own map. Secondly, for saving the map you can use `octomap_saver` node.

---

Originally posted by [ajain](https://answers.ros.org/users/18985/ajain/) with karma: 281 on 2014-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thiagopj](https://answers.ros.org/users/19552/thiagopj/) on 2014-12-11**:
I tried to use with octomap_server, but didn't understand when you say "change the subcribed topics using remap". How can i do that ?
And about the usage of octomap_saver, i just need to build a map in rgbdslamv2 and then run this node to save (And then not use the GUI) ?

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-12-11**:
you can run the octomap_server node from a launch file (this is one way), and within the `<node> </node>` tags you can specify another tag

`<remap from="/octomap_defualt_topic" to="/actually_listen_to_this_one"/>`

**Comment by [Thiagopj](https://answers.ros.org/users/19552/thiagopj/) on 2014-12-11**:
In my octomap_server.launch i have this line `<remap from="cloud_in" to="/rgbdslam/batch_clouds" />` but how can i check if its correct ? And where do i see who's the right one ? When i run `rosrun octomap_server octomap_saver file.(bt|ot)` i got an error that msg.data.size() is empty.

**Comment by [ajain](https://answers.ros.org/users/18985/ajain/) on 2014-12-11**:
You can use rqt_graph to see if all topics and nodes are correctly connected, or visualize topic published by octomap_server in rviz using Marker array data type. You won't get an error in using octomap_saver if data is correctly published by the server.

**Comment by [Thiagopj](https://answers.ros.org/users/19552/thiagopj/) on 2014-12-11**:
I did run rqt_graph, and i think everything is ok. See [here](http://oi62.tinypic.com/i6dwza.jpg).
As from RVIZ, using Marker array nothing happen. See [here](http://oi58.tinypic.com/28mobcp.jpg).
Any ideia of what is happening ? Thanks!

**Comment by [Thiagopj](https://answers.ros.org/users/19552/thiagopj/) on 2014-12-12**:
Sorry. I've fixed my links. [rqt_graph](http://postimg.org/image/5kkwm4lwp/). [MarkerArray](http://postimg.org/image/49hqrefop/). [rgbdslam.launch](http://postimg.org/image/mawabgkbt/). [octomap_server.launch](http://postimg.org/image/uf4eg76qx/).

**Comment by [Thiagopj](https://answers.ros.org/users/19552/thiagopj/) on 2014-12-12**:
My steps are: `roscore` && `roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch` && `roslaunch rgbdslam rgbdslam.launch` && `roslaunch rgbdslam octomap_server.launch`. After that i capture the frames in the GUI and try to save the octomap but no data is received.

**Comment by [ajain](https://answers.ros.org/users/18985/ajain/) on 2014-12-12**:
Firstly, please post a rqt_graph with topic names please. Secondly, try adding `output="screen"`  parameter in octomap_server.launch for the node to see the logs of octomap_server and understand what's going wrong. Also, FYI you don;t need to run roscore if you are using roslaunch

**Comment by [Eyshika](https://answers.ros.org/users/31786/eyshika/) on 2018-01-09**:
Are you using point cloud data to generate octomap ? If yes then how ?